# How to pass Bitmap into DLL function in C++ and Delphi?

Tags: delphi, visual-c++, dll

I want to create a DLL plugins to use with Delphi and other languages (mostly C++). 
How can I pass bitmaps in a C++ and Delphi-friendly way? Can it just be a handle to the Delphi TBitmap? C++ program should be able to decode it using WinApi, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot pass a Delphi `TBitmap` object since that is only meaningful to Delphi code. What you need to pass is an [`HBITMAP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx#hbitmap), a handle to a Windows bitmap.

The Delphi `TBitmap` class is just a wrapper around the Windows bitmap and can provide `HBITMAP` handles. The thing you need to watch out for is the ownership of those handles.

If you have a Delphi `TBitmap` you can get an `HBITMAP` by calling the [`ReleaseHandle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap.ReleaseHandle) method of a `TBitmap`. The handle returned by `ReleaseHandle` is no longer owned and managed by the `TBitmap` object which is exactly what you want. You pass that handle to the C++ code and let it become the owner. It is responsible for disposing of that handle.

The documentation for [`ReleaseHandle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap.ReleaseHandle) says:

> Returns the handle to the bitmap so that the TBitmap object no longer
>   knows about the handle.
>
> Use **ReleaseHandle** to disassociate the bitmap from the bitmap handle.
>   Use it when you need to give a bitmap handle to a routine or object
>   that will assume ownership (or destroy) the bitmap handle.

In the other direction your Delphi code would receive an [`HBITMAP`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap.Handle) from the C++ code and take on ownership. Do that by assigning to the `Handle` property of a `TBitmap` instance.

The details will vary from language to language, but no matter what, all will be able to deal with an `HBITMAP`.

Comment: So the code below would be good: `procedure ChangeBitmap(var BmpHandle: hBitmap);
var Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  Bmp.Handle := BmpHandle;

  /*change the bitmap*/

  BmpHandle := Bmp.ReleaseHandle;
end;`

Comment: That code doesn't make a lot of sense to me. `Bmp` is a local that's never instantiated. But, ignoring that, what is it doing?

Comment: I want to get a bitmap in a DLL, change it and return. I just want to make sure the kind of data types are fine.

Comment: OK, I see now. Yes, that would do it. Obviously you'd need to create `Bmp`!

Comment: Yes, right, thank you! Sorry for lack of enters- no idea how to make them in comments.

Comment: @Tom impossible in comments!

Comment: My Delphi DLL works perfectly from my Delphi code using hBitmap handles so it should be all fine with C++ too, thank you again!