# How to pass a bitmap to a dll written by Delphi in C#?

Tags: c#, image, delphi, dll, bitmap

I have a Delphi function in a dll written like this:

```
       function LensFlare(Bitmap: TBitmap; X, Y: Int32; Brightness: Real): TBitmap; StdCall;
       Begin
         // ...
         Result := Bitmap;
       End;
```

I want to use it in C#,
I have tried this but I was not successful:

```
    [DllImport("ImageProcessor")]
    static extern Bitmap LensFlare(Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y, double Brightness);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(@"d:\a.bmp");
        pictureBox1.Image = LensFlare(b, 100, 100, 50); // Error!
    }
```

Error: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi's `TBitmap` class is very different than .NET's `Bitmap` class. They are not compatible with each other, and neither is safe for interoperability purposes.

You will have to use a raw Win32 `HBITMAP` handle instead.

```pascal
function LensFlare(Bitmap: HBITMAP; X, Y: Int32; Brightness: Real): HBITMAP; StdCall;
Begin
  // ...
  Result := Bitmap;
End;
```

```cs
[DllImport("ImageProcessor")]
static extern IntPtr LensFlare(PtrInt bitmap, int x, int y, double Brightness);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(@"d:\a.bmp");
    IntPtr hbmp = LensFlare(b.GetHbitmap(), 100, 100, 50);
    try {
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromHbitmap(hbmp);
    }
    finally {
        DeleteObject(hbmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did the same thing but in C# this error occurs: "A generic error occurred in GDI+.". In Delphi I did "var B: TBitmap; ... B.Handle := Bitmap; B.SaveToFile("D:\A.BMP");" it works but "B.Handle := Bitmap;" causes a problem!.

Comment: how would i do it in reverse ? i call c# dll inside delphi and i want to return img

Comment: @BrianOrion passing around `HBITMAP` handles is the only interoperability option between Delphi bitmaps and .NET bitmaps.

Comment: No i meant as in i have c# dll where i set that the function will return IntPtr and then i call it in delphi...but here i dont get HBITMAP but integer so in c#  `IntPtr GetImg(string data); ` and then when i build the TLB into delphi the function i dll is `function GetImage(const data: WideString; out pRetVal: Integer): HResult; stdcall;`  but why ?

Comment: Because that is simply how that code translates. Simply typecast the returned integer to `HBITMAP` and then assign it to a `TBitmap.Handle`.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use this function. It's not even safe to use between two Delphi modules unless you use packages. You cannot pass native Delphi classes across a module boundary like that.

You'll need to switch to an interop friendly type. The obvious option is to use an `HBITMAP`. You will need to modify the Delphi library. If you don't have the source you will need to contact the original developer.

Comment: I have the source code but how can I do it? I need a working example.

Comment: So write one. The bitmap classes in both c# and delphi provide means to interop with Win32 bitmap handles. Read some documentation and don't be helpless. Make more effort.

Comment: not testet ....   
procedure ChangeBitmap(var BmpHandle: hBitmap ; var Bmp: TBitmap );  
begin 
      Bmp.Handle := BmpHandle; 
      BmpHandle := Bmp.ReleaseHandle; 
end;

Comment: or here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625158/how-to-pass-bitmap-into-dll-function-in-c-and-delphi?rq=1

Comment: I did the same thing but in C# this error occurs: "A generic error occurred in GDI+.". In Delphi I did "var B: TBitmap; ... B.Handle := Bitmap; B.SaveToFile("D:\A.BMP");" it works but "B.Handle := Bitmap;" causes a problem!.